# Failed scheduled job

Tags: sql-server, powershell, jobs

I have created 3 jobs in my MS SQL Server

[image]

The job returns an error on **2. Remove top 4 lines**

> Message
>   Executed as user: myDomain\administrator. The process could not be created for step 2 of job 0xA849BBB21D41B64387336C2CAA7FB632 (reason: The system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed.

[image]

The job is a CMD script that works fine in CMD window

```
more +4 "D:\export\BRANCHES.XML" >"D:\export\BRANCHES2.XML"
```

Also, my third job is not working either. It wont change replace the text.

[image]

Here is the code

```
(Get-Content D:\export\BRANCHES2.XML) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '(1 rows(s) affected)','MyValue'}  | Out-File  D:\export\BRANCHES3.XML
```

Both the directory and the file exists on **D:\export**

Comment: Ensure the SQL Server Agent Service Account security context has access to D:\export folder and that this is a server disk drive partition on the SQL Server instance you are running the job from.  Otherwise, ensure it has SHARE and NTFS permissions and use UNC path instead to point to to the input and output files BOTH.

Comment: how do i check the access?

Comment: Right click on the folder that on the "D" drive of the Server where it runs, select properties, and ensure it has MODIFY access.  Whatever security the SQL Server Agent Service Account runs as it what should have MODIFY access and this path should exist from the server it is running and not some client machine you are running SSMS through; otherwise, use UNC path to a location that's this account can access.

Comment: Look at this link for what I'm talking about ont he NTFS permissions... http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-setting.htm

Comment: For your XML value parsing, see these two articles where the first one has a 'File Operations' section at the bottom that talks about Get-Content and the -raw switch to use for XML parsing, and the other has some examples as well for REGEX, etc. . .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716845/how-can-i-parse-an-xml-file-and-delete-text-between-two-tags-using-powershell and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517524/change-xml-tags-within-powershell-and-keep-content

Comment: I dig a bit deeper and found out that the log says: **Cannot find the path** eventhough `D:\export\`  and  `D:\export\BRANCHES.XML` both exists

Comment: Sure sounds like permissions issue; have you confirmed the account used by SQL Server Agent has read and write access to the `D:\export` folder, as recommended by @PJMahoney ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working.
I first made a PS script in PowerShell ISE like this:

[image]

and then added it as a job in MSSQL